# Writing an s-expression with indented lines?

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment

I'm writing some notes on parsing expressions, and one thing I want to illustrate is prefix notation equations. With this in mind, I want to be able to indent certain pieces of an s-expression. For instance, here's what I'm looking for:

```
(−
  (+
    (∗ 7 −9)
    (−6
      (/ −3 2))))
```

However, I can't figure out an easy way to do this. Ideally, these expressions would also be centered and have the ability to "unindent" some subexpressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the use of `minted` is the good choice here. With the code below, you will obtain the following output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{lisp}
(-
  (+
    (* 7 -9)
    (-6
      (/ -3 2))))
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't think about using minted! That's a great idea.

Answer (score 8):

An option would be to use the `tabbing` environment (inside a `minipage` and `center` environment for centering the construction)

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabbing}
    $(-$\=\+\\
      $(+$\=\+\\
         $(\times$ $7$ $-9$\\
         $(-$\=\ $6$\+\\
             $(/$ $-3$ $2)))))$
\end{tabbing}   
\end{minipage}  
\end{center}
```

[image]

In the `tabbing` environment `\=` sets a tab stop, `\+` move the first stop in the next lines to the “next” tab stop.

Comment: you'd want `{-}` to avoid the infix spacing  on -  `(* 7 -9)` is "7 times -9 " not "star 7 minus 9" and `\=` before 6 not after as the arguments of `(-` are `6` and `(/ -3 2)` so should be indended the same amount

Answer (score 8):

[image]

This obeys newlines but ignores white space re-indenting acording to () nesting depth. * and − can be entered as ascii * and - or Unicode ∗ − as in the question.

The whole expression is centred on its longest line

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{\ensuremath{-}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2217}{\ensuremath{*}}
\newcount\sexpdepth
\catcode`\(\active
\catcode`\)\active
\catcode`\-\active
\catcode`\*\active
\newenvironment{sexp}
{\center
\global\sexpdepth=0 %
\bgroup
\catcode`\(\active
\catcode`\)\active
\catcode`\-\active
\catcode`\*\active
\edef-{$\string-$}%
\edef*{$\string*$}%
\edef({\string(\global\advance\sexpdepth1 }%
\edef){\string)\global\advance\sexpdepth\string-1 }%
\def\obeyedline{\\\hspace{\sexpdepth em}}%
\obeylines
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}}
{\end{tabular}\egroup
\endcenter}
\catcode`\(12
\catcode`\)12
\catcode`\-12
\catcode`\*12

\begin{document}

\begin{sexp}
  (+
1
2
3)
\end{sexp}

\begin{sexp}
(−
  (+
  (∗ 7 −9)
  (−6
      (/ 1 −32))
          (* 1 2)
    5))  
\end{sexp}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using an ordinary `verbatim` environment.

[image: Sample verbatim]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
(-
  (+
    (* 7 -9)
    (-6
      (/ -3 2))))
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Or you can treat this as programming code and use either `listings` or `minted`.  Here is a minted example, treating this as lisp like material.  See the [documentation of minted](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) to see how to set the package up; you will need to remember to compile with `-shell-escape`.

[image: Sample lisp]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{cl}
(-
  (+
    (* 7 -9)
    (-6
      (/ -3 2))))
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\noindent (-

(+

\indent\indent $(\times 7 - 9)$

\indent\indent (-6

\indent\indent\indent (/ - 32))))
\end{document}
```

[image]

To achieve this multi-indent you need to use `\indent` multiple times.

Comment: eek why a (infix!!) minus before 9 but hyphens on the other lines,  why no space after `*`  why are the arguments  of - indented by different amounts?